# Dockerized webapp - hot reloading

Tags: docker, webpack, web-applications, webpack-dev-server

I have just dockerized my application that uses nginx, webpack, flaskapp and postgres, however I currently have to run:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

to implement any changes which is super slow as it recreates the whole environment, but it works.

I want to add webpack's hot reloading feature but despite hours of searching I'm struggling to conceptually understand what I need to do to get it running?

Even if I create a separate container to run the webpack-dev-server plugin, how do I set it up to recognise changes AND communicate with the flask backend?

Here is my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file... I'm very new to docker so any pointers would be much appreciated!

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update the apt-get list
RUN apt-get update -y

# Install python packages
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN mkdir -p /opt/services/flaskapp/src
COPY requirements.txt /opt/services/flaskapp/src/
WORKDIR /opt/services/flaskapp/src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install curl
RUN apt-get install -y curl

# Install nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install webpack globally
RUN npm install webpack -g

COPY . /opt/services/flaskapp/src
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 5090
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:9.6.5"
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    env_file:
      - env_file
    networks:
      - db_nw
  flaskapp:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - env_file
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/flaskapp/src
    networks:
      - db_nw
      - web_nw
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:1.13.5"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - web_nw
    depends_on:
      - flaskapp
networks:
  db_nw:
    driver: bridge
  web_nw:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask supports code reload when in debug mode. So what you should do is the specify in your `env_file` the followings:

```
  FLASK_DEBUG=1 (or True)
  FLASK_APP=./app.py
```

With this you can change also the `CMD` part as following:

```
  CMD ["python", "-m" "flask run"]
```

Btw for production environments keep in mind that it's better to use `gunicorn` instead simple flask app run